# Append human readable timestamp of last edit to filename

Tags: bash, files, timestamps

I would like to add the time of the last change to the file to its filename using the bash.

For example this output of `ls -la`:

```
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 beginner beginner 5382 Dec  1 17:18 B_F1-1.xml
```

should become

```
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 beginner beginner 5382 Dec  1 17:18 B_F1-1_20141201T1718.xml
```

How could I do this to all files in .?

Comment: How did you get `20141201T1718`?

Comment: @KasiyA It is from the timestamp that the file has in the system: 'Dec 1 -> 2014 12 01' and then T followed by the time 17:18.

Comment: @KasiyA its the time stamp of the file, see the output of `ls -la` in the question.

Comment: Sounds like a use case for version control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
EXT=${FILE#*.}
NAME=${FILE%%.*}

mv "$FILE" "$NAME$(date --reference "$FILE" '+%Y%m%dT%H%M').$EXT"
```

in  a script, if your `date` supports `--reference`, which picks up the last modification date of the reference file.

Comment: thanks! this works if I removoe the ' ' around $FILE in the date function.

Comment: @Beginner Indeed. My mistake, I think I confused the quoting.

Comment: You should still use double quotes within `"$( ... "$var" ...)"` -- the command substitution spawns a subshell so the "inner" quotes do not clash with the "outer" ones

Comment: @glennjackman I was looking up the quoting rules for command substitution, if that's the correct way, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think this could work:

```sh
for i in *; do 
   fileTime=$(stat -c %Y "$i");  #Get last modification (since EPOCH)
   formatDate=$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%m -d @"$fileTime"); #Get time in format YYYYMMDDTHHmm
   mv "${i%%.*}"_"$formatDate"."${i#*.}"; #Appends "formatDate" before extension
done
```

Regards.

Comment: I posted wrong minute parameter. It must be capital M (%M), instead of %m (which means month).

Comment: thank you. One small issue is that the result is filename.xml_formatdate

Comment: You are right. Look at muru sample and modify `mv "$i" "$i"_"$formatDate"`to `mv  "$i" "${i%%.*}"_"$formatDate"."${i#*.}"`. Sorry ;)

Answer (score 1):

This can all be done as a oneliner.

```
for i in *.* ; do mv "$i" "${i%.*}_$(date --reference "$i" +%Y%m%dT%H%M).${i##*.}"; done
```

For a literal *timestamp*, i.e., seconds since the epoch, you can just use:

```
for i in *.* ; do mv "$i" "${i%.*}_$(date --reference "$i" +%s).${i##*.}"; done
```

This has a safety check to only operate on files whose names contain dots; it correctly handles files with spaces in the names; and it assumes (as would usually be the case) that the LAST dot separated field is the extension, rather than the FIRST dot separated field being the filename and the rest being an extension.

Credit to muru for the `--reference` bit; I didn't know about that option.